# Combine attachments in one Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I am looking for combining notes and attachments related to 2 different objects in 3rd object.

Object1 has related list of notes and attachments and Object2 has related list of notes and attachments.

I have created 2 visualforce pages related to Object3 and added those in separate section But how do I combine those 2 relatedlist.

Note - both object1 and object2 have realated List's list attribute value ="CombinedAttachments"

Comment: I worked with custom VF and apex controller extension and it worked. Sorry - I am not sure about exposing code here (Don't know the company policy)

Comment: Sandeep, check the [ask] page. It will be nearly impossible to help without code. Most places will let you post excerpts of code, though some people simply either use pseudo code or real code (simplified) with changed object names.

Comment: I am new to it. I will keep that in mind next time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use `apex:relatedList` to combine other objects related lists. The standard related list component relies on the `StandardController` for the page's record, and due to only the third object being present in the `StandardController`, it'll only show that objects records.

---

There are ways around this, but they will rely on apex and visualforce. By creating a [custom visualforce component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_component.htm), you can style it identical to the related lists on the page, and provide the other object ids for use in the component to filter your data appropriately.

If this is a road you want to go down, try the [Visualforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/visualforce_fundamentals) if you haven't, and [ask a new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you run into issues with developing your own component.

Comment: I tried creating custom visualforce page and added it to the layout and it worked perfectly. I used Notes and Attachments objects and created 2 page block tables to show it similar to the existing ones.

Comment: If this answer helped you, consider [marking it as accepted](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). That way, others who come to this question will be able to tell that this answer helped you.